# Using get_posts, I need to use a combination of OR & AND relations

Tags: get-posts, meta-query, tax-query

Using WordPress v4.6, I set up arguments for `get_posts()` based on price (2 conditions), sku, and categories like this:

```
[meta_query] => Array
    (
        [relation] => AND
        [0] => Array
            (
                [key] => _price
                [value] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 0
                        [1] => 5
                    )

                [type] => DECIMAL
                [compare] => BETWEEN
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [key] => _price
                [value] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 50.01
                        [1] => 100
                    )

                [type] => DECIMAL
                [compare] => BETWEEN
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [key] => _sku
                [value] => batte
                [compare] => like
            )

    )

[tax_query] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [taxonomy] => product_cat
                [field] => id
                [terms] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 26
                        [1] => 20
                    )

            )

    )
```

I set `AND` relations, but actually I need `OR` relations between 2 prices and `AND` relations for the rest of the comparisons.

What is the correct syntax for this query?

Answer (score 0):

Nested arrays can be used to create complex Meta Query's.

An example of how this would apply to your situation.

```
$meta_query_args = array(
    'relation' => 'AND', 
    array(
        // Conditions
    ),
    array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            // Conditions
        ),
        array(
            // Conditions
        )
    )
);
```

For more information check: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query